# Merging entity with empty related entity in one to many relationship

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have an entity that I have deserialized using JMSSerializer. One of the related items is an ArrayCollection that has no entries in it when the parent object is initially created.

The relationship looks like this

Assembly > has many > HistoryEntries

When I try to merge the deserialized Assembly entity where HistoryEntries is an empty ArrayCollection I get the following error

`The given entity of type 'XES\\MpmBundle\\Entity\\History' (unassigned) has no identity/no id values set. It cannot be added to the identity map.`

How can I merge and persist an entity where one or more of the relationships has no related entities?